# Extra backslashes appear in raw strings

Tags: python, string

I am having trouble with extra backslashes that appear when I display a raw string. I want the raw string to equal `9.2\\(4\\)4`, but I keep getting `9.2\\\\(4\\\\)4` in the `Primary_Image` variable.  However, the program prints `9.2\\(4\\)4`.

```
import re

def Convert_Image_name_for_regex(image):
    image = re.sub(r'.*asa|k8.bin.*','',image)
    image = image.replace(r"-", r"", 2)
    image = image[:1] + r'.' + image[1:]
    image = image[:3] + r'\(' + image[3:]
    image = image[:6] + r'\)' + image[6:]
    return image

Primary_Image = r'asa924-4-k8.bin'
Primary_Image = Convert_Image_name_for_regex(Primary_Image)
print Primary_Image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\` represents an [escaped backslash](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). If its prints out correctly, it should be just fine!

To explain a little better, there are not two backslashes there. In Python, the backslash is a special character. If you want to treat it as a normal character, you must escape it. Coincidentally, escaping is exactly what the backslash is for. I don't understand why you would want to remove that, and in fact - I don't think you ever could. To enter a backslash on its own would mean that the next character would be escaped. The string `"\\"` contains only one character (a literal backslash). The string `r"\\"` contains two (the escape character, and literal backslash). When printed out or used in any sort of I/O, it should be treated as a single character.

If somehow this second backslash is causing problems, it may be because you're trying to use it as a literal marked with an `r`. Just remove this `r` when using the string to have Python treat `"\\"` as one character as expected.